# What is the difference between Web.config and Applicationhost.config in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create an OData Endpoint with help from this documentary:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint
They use VS 2017 and I use VS 2022.

At step X I have to open the Web.config file, which doesn't exist. The only .config file I can find is the applicationhost.config. Is it the same and the Web.config is (may be) just the .config file of an older version?

Comment: Web.config and Application.config are essentially the same things. Web.config for ASP.NET and Application.config for everything else. Don't ask me why the difference in names, I think it's for historical reasons.

Comment: But I created a ASP .NET and got the Application.config file.

Comment: Yeah... not sure what happened there. I would expect and ASP.NET project to have a Web.config as does the Microsoft Learn article you linked to. However why that happened wasn't your question.

Comment: Are you sure it's called `Application.config` and not `App.config`?

Comment: It's called applicationhost.config.

Comment: If it isn't a duplicate, this is a really valuable question; I'm astonished it's not been asked before (if that indeed is the case).

Answer (score 2):

`ApplicationHost.config` is a global IIS configuration file (ie, per machine) that gets loaded before your `web.config` settings (ie per site or app).

Also `app.config` defines the executable settings for your application, and since Asp.Net Core generates executable hosts, that is also important.